# Change font in `quotechap` chapter number

Tags: titles, chapters

Say, with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[]{quotchap} % <- option other than avantgarde, beramono, berasans, beraserif, biolinum, bookman, charter, courier, helvetica, kpfonts, libertine, lmodern, newcentury, palatino, times, utopia
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
For mange Aar siden levede en Keiser, som holdt saa uhyre meget af smukke nye Kl\ae der, at han gav alle sine Penge ud for ret at blive pyntet. Han br\o d sig ikke om sine Soldater, br\o d sig ei om Comedie eller om at kj\o re i Skoven, uden alene for at vise sine nye Kl\ae der. Han havde en Kjole for hver Time paa Dagen, og ligesom man siger om en Konge, han er i Raadet, saa sagde man altid her: >>Keiseren er i Garderoben
\end{document}
```

I would like to change the font option (which will be used to render the chapter number) to [TEX Gyre Chorus](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/texgyrechorus/) font. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the `quotchap` documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/quotchap/quotchap.pdf), it says if you want to use a font not normally provided to style the chapter number you can use `\qsetcnfont`.  In the case of TEX Gyre Chorus, you would use `\qsetcnfont{qzc}`.  For other fonts, the "Finding the Font Name" part of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251/189103) describes how you can find the appropriate font name to use as an argument to `\qsetcnfont`.